# Docker: How to use selenium server to do nightwatchJS test?

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, gitlab

I don't know how to run a selenium server with my NodeJS application, whose files are located in the `./bundle` folder of the custom `e2e:latest` docker image.

I think I have to add the selenium server and webdriver chrome into the Dockerfile for the `e2e:latest` image, don't I?

This is what I have done so far:

I've created a java:8-jre based docker image with NodeJS and nightwatchJS:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8-jre

## Node.js setup
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

## Nightwatch
RUN npm install -g nightwatch
```

This image is then used for the test:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - deploy
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - meteor npm install --production
    - meteor build $PACKAGE_PATH --directory
    # Maybe something like...? - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:e2e .

nightwatch:
  image: e2e:latest
  stage: e2e
  tags:
    - e2e
  before_script:
    - cd ./bundle
  script:
    - nightwatch
```

The configuration looks like this:

**nightwatch.conf.js**

```
module.exports = {
    'src_folders'           : ['test/e2e'],
    'output_folder'         : 'reports',
    'custom_commands_path'  : '',
    'custom_assertions_path': '',
    'page_objects_path'     : '',
    'globals_path'          : '',
    'test_runner'           : {
        'type'   : 'mocha',
        'options': {
            'ui'      : 'bdd',
            'reporter': 'list'
        }
    },

    'selenium': {
        'start_process': false,
        'server_path'  : '',
        'log_path'     : '',
        'host'         : '127.0.0.1',
        'port'         : 4444,
        'cli_args'     : {
            'webdriver.chrome.driver': './bin/chromedriver'
        }
    },

    'test_settings': {
        'default': {
            'launch_url'   : 'http://localhost',
            'selenium_port': 4444,
            'selenium_host': 'localhost',
            'silent'       : true,
            'screenshots'  : {
                'enabled': true,
                'path'   : 'reports/error-screenshots'
            },
            'desiredCapabilities': {
                'browserName'      : 'chrome',
                'javascriptEnabled': true,
                'acceptSslCerts'   : true
            }
        },

        'chrome': {
            'desiredCapabilities': {
                'browserName'      : 'chrome',
                'javascriptEnabled': true,
                'acceptSslCerts'   : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? What kind of output do you get from the job in Gitlab CI?

Comment: Right now there is no selenium server running. I don't know how to set this up in this case

Comment: @Jawad And now I'm thinking to use *nightmare*. As far es I understand, I don't need a selenium server

Comment: Looks like for nightwatch you need a web driver like selenium and then a web browser while nightmare looks more standalone

Comment: But how do I implement this into my Dockerfile and yml file? Think nightmare would be simpler, right?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this is suitable for Gitlab CI but take a look at [Selenoid](http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) project. This is a small (6 Mb) binary that launches browsers in separate Docker containers or by starting Webdriver process directly. So if container approach is not suitable for your needs try to pack Selenoid + e.g. [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) + Chrome to the same container with Node.js. **No need** to install Java when using Selenoid.

Comment: I like the container approach. But how do I use the node application image for the selenium container? That is my problem.

Comment: I mean, I have already an docker image, which contains my node application (let's call it `app:latest`) and now I have a Selenoid docker container. The selenoid docker image/container is then running at localhost:4444 (if I understand the docs correctly). But how do I connect the node application to this setup? Or do I have to copy the files? If yes, where...?

Comment: What I propose is to use any Node.js base container + add Selenoid binary there + ChromeDriver binary + Chrome itself. No need to have Java, Selenium server and so on.

Comment: @user3142695 just use your application container as base and add Selenoid. Then in test just go to localhost.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but how do I add selenoid to my existing docker image (which has the node application files)?

Comment: I have updated the post. Add build stage of the gitlab CI. With `meteor build` a node application is created. So now - if I understand you correctly - I have to create a node image with selenoid and chrome. Right? Could you post some codelines for that?

Comment: Something like: https://gist.github.com/vania-pooh/fafe7be5f97c09bfdfe4304433cfe63f

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. App.js would be my node application?

Comment: Yes, I don't know JS very well, just copied some hello-world.